# Using ES6 Classes as Angular 1.x directives

Tags: javascript, angularjs, class, angularjs-directive, ecmascript-6

I'm doing a small project to play around the goody bag the ES6 is bringing, I'm trying to set register a class as an angular directive, but I'm running into this error "TypeError: Cannot call a class as a function", but from the examples I'm finding they just write the class and register it with angular as a directive. Here's my directive.

```
class dateBlock {
  constructor () {
    this.template = '/app/dateblock/dateblock.html';
    this.restrict = 'AE';
    this.scope = {};
  }
};

export default dateBlock
```

and my index where I import it and then declare it.

```
import calendarController from './calendar/calendar.js'
import dateBlock from './dateblock/dateblock.js'

function setup($stateProvider) {
    $stateProvider
      .state('base', {
        url: '',
        controller: calendarController,
        templateUrl: '/app/calendar/calendar.html'
      });
    };

setup.$inject = ['$stateProvider']

var app = angular.module('calApp',['ngAnimate','ui.router','hmTouchEvents', 'templates'])
  .config(setup)
  .controller('calendarController', calendarController)
  .directive('dateBlock', dateBlock)
```

If I missed some crucial step I'd love to hear it. Also side question is it cleaner to import all the apps components to the index and register them all there or export the app and import and register within the components?

Comment: `directive` expects a function that returns a map of thingies such as `scope`, `template`, etc. I would try `new dateBlock ()` instead of just `dateBlock `. And I would rename `dateBlock` into `DateBlock` :-)

Comment: Thanks, I renamed to DateBlock. If I create a new instance of DateBlock I get an object with the template restrict and scope properties, should I be registering the DateBlock constructor to as the directive, and include a this.link or this.controller property inside of the constructor?

Comment: Isn't it amazing that with project as big as Angular, there isn't any 'good' way to write directives using ES6 syntax? I couldn't find a single solution that would not look like either over engineering or a hack just to make it work.

Answer (score 66):

From my point of view, there is no need to use external libraries like register.js, because you can create directive as a ES6 class in this way:

```
class MessagesDirective {
    constructor() {
        this.restrict = 'E'
        this.templateUrl = 'messages.html'
        this.scope = {}
    }

    controller($scope, $state, MessagesService) {
        $scope.state = $state;
        $scope.service = MessagesService;
    }

    link(scope, element, attrs) {
        console.log('state', scope.state)
        console.log('service', scope.service)
    }
}
angular.module('messages').directive('messagesWidget', () => new MessagesDirective)
```

Using directive controller allows you to inject dependencies, even without additional declaration (ex. `MessagesDirective.$inject = ['$scope', '$state', 'MessagesService']`), so you can use services in link function via scope if you need.

Comment: Not over engineered and clear. I'd upvote more if I could.  Thank you.

Comment: For the record, if you use `ng-annotate`, do not forget to annotate the `controller` with `ngInject`: `controller($scope, $state, MessagesService) {'ngInject'; ...}`. Just saying that because I wasted 2 hours on this, :ashamed:.

Comment: @andrew genius, thanks! I would have never figured that out.

Comment: This doesn't work if the is code is minified and the variable names get mangled. A possible workaround would be telling the minifier not to mangle variable names, but that would result in a bigger bundle, ymmv.

Answer (score 48):

As mentioned in a comment, the `module.directive()` method expects a factory function rather than a constructor.

The most simple way would be to wrap your class in a function that returns an instance:

```
angular.module('app')
    .directive('dateBlock', () => new DateBlock());
```

However, this will only work in the most limited sense - it does not allow for dependency injection and the `compile` and `link` functions of your directive (if defined) will not work as expected.

In fact, this is a problem I have looked into quite extensively and it turned out to be fairly tricky to solve (for me at least).

I wrote an extensive article covering my solution, but as far as you are concerned I can point you to the discussion of the two main issues that need to be resolved:

1. [Dynamically converting a class definition into an angular-compatible factory function](http://www.michaelbromley.co.uk/blog/350/exploring-es6-classes-in-angularjs-1-x#_section-factories)
2. [Allowing a directive's `link` and `compile` functions to be defined as class methods](http://www.michaelbromley.co.uk/blog/350/exploring-es6-classes-in-angularjs-1-x#_section-directives)

The full solution involves too much code to paste here, I think, but I have put together a working demo project which allows you to define a directive as an ES6 class like this:

```
class MyDirective {
    /*@ngInject*/
    constructor($interval) {
        this.template = '<div>I\'m a directive!</div>';
        this.restrict = 'E';
        this.scope = {}
        // etc. for the usual config options

        // allows us to use the injected dependencies
        // elsewhere in the directive (e.g. compile or link function)
        this.$interval = $interval;
    }

    // optional compile function
    compile(tElement) {
        tElement.css('position', 'absolute');
    }

    // optional link function
    link(scope, element) {
        this.$interval(() => this.move(element), 1000);
    }

    move(element) {
        element.css('left', (Math.random() * 500) + 'px');
        element.css('top', (Math.random() * 500) + 'px');
    }
}

// `register` is a helper method that hides all the complex magic that is needed to make this work.
register('app').directive('myDirective', MyDirective);
```

Check out the [demo repo here](https://github.com/michaelbromley/angular-es6) and [here is the code behind `register.directive()`](https://github.com/michaelbromley/angular-es6/blob/master/src/app/utils/register.js#L16)

Comment: I've run into similar problems when trying to convert a factory service that was returning a $resource instance. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28992224/how-to-convert-an-angular-resource-factory-not-service-to-es6

Comment: I would highly avoid 'hacks' like this; its gonna make it a tough road for the 2.0 conversion.

Comment: @amcdnl True, it certainly is a bit hacky. In my article I do not recommend it as a good way to do things, rather it is an exploration of how it *could* be done. Since this question is about how to do it, and the author states that this is a small project to play with ES6, I'd hazard that the upgrade path in this case would not be a major concern. For large or production projects, I would tend to agree with you.

Comment: Is there any way to add a controller with service dependency in this structure?

Answer (score 22):

@Michael is right on the money:

> the module.directive() method expects a factory function

However I solved it using another technique, a little cleaner I suppose, It works fine for me, it's not perfect though...
I defined a static method that returns a the factory expected by module()

```
class VineDirective {
    constructor($q) {
        this.restrict = 'AE';
        this.$q = $q;
    }

    link(scope, element, attributes) {
        console.log("directive link");
    }

    static directiveFactory($q){
        VineDirective.instance = new VineDirective($q);
        return VineDirective.instance;
    }
}

VineDirective.directiveFactory.$inject = ['$q'];

export { VineDirective }
```

And in my app I do:

```
angular.module('vineyard',[]).directive('vineScroller', VineDirective.directiveFactory)
```

I believe there's no other way to use classes + directives that going through hacks like this at this point, just pick the easy one ;-)

Comment: why don't you just return new VineDirective($q) directly?

Comment: `static directiveFactory($q){
    'ngInject'; 
    return new VineDirective($q);
}`

This also works. I now think this pattern is most solid. 
If your directive is taking in a form or input controller, using the directive's controller in the link function to deal with dependencies seems problematic.

Answer (score 21):

A simpler, cleaner and more readable solution.

```
class ClipBoardText {

  constructor() {
    console.log('constructor');

    this.restrict = 'A';
    this.controller = ClipBoardTextController;
  }

  link(scope, element, attr, ctr) {

    console.log('ctr', ctr);
    console.log('ZeroClipboard in link', ctr.ZeroClipboard);
    console.log('q in link', ctr.q);

  }

  static directiveFactory() {
    return new ClipBoardText();
  }
}

// do not $inject like this
// ClipBoardText.$inject = ['$q'];

class ClipBoardTextController {
  constructor(q) {
    this.q = q;
    this.ZeroClipboard = 'zeroclipboard';
  }
}

ClipBoardTextController.$inject = ['$q'];


export default ClipBoardText.directiveFactory;
```

You cannot get `$q` in `link` function, `this` in `link` will be `undefined` or `null`. [exploring-es6-classes-in-angularjs-1-x#_section-factories](http://www.michaelbromley.co.uk/blog/350/exploring-es6-classes-in-angularjs-1-x#_section-factories)

> when Angular invokes the link function, it is no longer in the context of the class instance, and therefore this.$interval will be undefined

So make use of the `controller` function in the directive, and inject dependencies or anything that you want to access in the `link` function.

Comment: You need import ClipBoardTextController from 'ClipBoardTextController';

Comment: This seems to be a clean approach, particularly since you don't have to do anything fancy when registering your directive on a module. I'm not sure what @geniuscarrier is getting at, either, if the controller is defined in the same ES6 module. I used ng-annotate on the controller's constructor. The only extra I'm dealing with is passing context so I can use the injectables in other methods on the directive's class, but otherwise, I think this is a good solution. Thanks

Answer (score 6):

My solution:

```
class myDirective {
   constructor( $timeout, $http ) {
       this.restrict = 'E';
       this.scope = {};

       this.$timeout = $timeout;
       this.$http = $http;
   }
   link() {
       console.log('link myDirective');
   }
   static create() {
       return new myDirective(...arguments);
   }
}

myDirective.create.$inject = ['$timeout', '$http'];

export { myDirective }
```

and in the main app file

```
app.directive('myDirective', myDirective.create)
```

Answer (score 3):

In my project I use a syntax sugar for injections. And ES6 makes it pretty simple to use injectable factories for directives avoiding too much duplicate code. This code allows injection inheritance, uses annotated injections and so on. Check this:

### First step

Declare base class for all angular controllers\directives\services - InjectableClient. **Its main task - set all injected params as properties** for 'this'. This behavior can be overridden, see examples below.

```
class InjectionClient {

    constructor(...injected) {
        /* As we can append injections in descendants we have to process only injections passed directly to current constructor */ 
        var injectLength = this.constructor.$inject.length;
        var injectedLength = injected.length;
        var startIndex = injectLength - injectedLength;
        for (var i = startIndex; i < injectLength; i++) {
            var injectName = this.constructor.$inject[i];
            var inject = injected[i - startIndex];
            this[injectName] = inject;
        }
    }

    static inject(...injected) {
        if (!this.$inject) { 
            this.$inject = injected; 
        } else {
            this.$inject = injected.concat(this.$inject);
        }
    };
}
```

For example, if we call SomeClassInheritedFromInjectableClient.inject('$scope'), in directive or controller we will use it as 'this.$scope'

### Second step

Declare the base class for directive with static method "factory()", which binds $injected property of directive class to factory function. And also "compile()" method, which binds the context of link function to the directive itself. Its allows to use our injected values inside the link function as this.myInjectedService.

```
class Directive extends InjectionClient {
    compile() {
        return this.link.bind(this);
    }

    static factory() {
        var factoryFunc = (...injected) => {
            return new this(...injected);
        }
        factoryFunc.$inject = this.$inject;
        return factoryFunc;
    }
}
```

### Third step

Now we can declare as much directive classes as possible. With inheritance. And we can set up injections in simple way with spread arrays (just dont forget call super method). See examples:

```
class DirectiveFirst extends Directive {
}

DirectiveFirst.inject('injA', 'injB', 'injC');


class DirectiveSecond extends DirectiveFirst {

    constructor(injD, ...injected) {
        super(...injected);
        this.otherInjectedProperty = injD;
    }
}
// See appended injection does not hurt the ancestor class
DirectiveSecond.inject('injD');

class DirectiveThird extends DirectiveSecond {

    constructor(...injected) {
        // Do not forget call the super method in overridden constructors
        super(...injected);
    }
}
```

### The last step

Now register directives with angular in simple way:

```
angular.directive('directiveFirst', DirectiveFirst.factory());
angular.directive('directiveSecond', DirectiveSecond.factory());
angular.directive('directiveThird', DirectiveThird.factory());
```

Now test the code:

```
var factoryFirst = DirectiveFirst.factory();
var factorySec = DirectiveSecond.factory();
var factoryThird = DirectiveThird.factory();


var directive = factoryFirst('A', 'B', 'C');
console.log(directive.constructor.name + ' ' + JSON.stringify(directive));

directive = factorySec('D', 'A', 'B', 'C');
console.log(directive.constructor.name + ' ' + JSON.stringify(directive));

directive = factoryThird('D', 'A', 'B', 'C');
console.log(directive.constructor.name + ' ' + JSON.stringify(directive));
```

This will return:

```
DirectiveFirst {"injA":"A","injB":"B","injC":"C"}
DirectiveSecond {"injA":"A","injB":"B","injC":"C","otherInjectedProperty":"D"}
DirectiveThird {"injA":"A","injB":"B","injC":"C","otherInjectedProperty":"D"}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
class ToggleShortcut{
constructor($timeout, authService, $compile, $state){

    var initDomEvents = function ($element, $scope) {

        var shortcut_dropdown = $('#shortcut');

        $compile(shortcut_dropdown)($scope);

        $scope.goToShortCutItem = function(state, params){
            var p = params || null;

            if(state === 'app.contacts.view'){
                var authProfile = authService.profile;
                if(authProfile){
                    p = {
                        id:authProfile.user_metadata.contact_id
                    };
                }
            }

            $state.go(state, p);
            window.setTimeout(shortcut_buttons_hide, 300);
        };

        $element.on('click', function () {
            if (shortcut_dropdown.is(":visible")) {
                shortcut_buttons_hide();
            } else {
                shortcut_buttons_show();
            }

        });

        // SHORTCUT buttons goes away if mouse is clicked outside of the area
        $(document).mouseup(function (e) {
            if (shortcut_dropdown && !shortcut_dropdown.is(e.target) && shortcut_dropdown.has(e.target).length === 0) {
                shortcut_buttons_hide();
            }
        });

        // SHORTCUT ANIMATE HIDE
        function shortcut_buttons_hide() {
            shortcut_dropdown.animate({
                height: "hide"
            }, 300, "easeOutCirc");
            $('body').removeClass('shortcut-on');

        }

        // SHORTCUT ANIMATE SHOW
        function shortcut_buttons_show() {
            shortcut_dropdown.animate({
                height: "show"
            }, 200, "easeOutCirc");
            $('body').addClass('shortcut-on');
        }
    };

    var link = function($scope, $element){
        $timeout(function(){
            initDomEvents($element, $scope);
        });
    };

    this.restrict = 'EA';
    this.link = link;
}
}

toggleShortcut.$inject = ['$timeout', 'authService', '$compile', '$state'];

function toggleShortcut($timeout, authService, $compile, $state){
return new ToggleShortcut($timeout, authService, $compile, $state);
}

angular.module('app.layout').directive('toggleShortcut', toggleShortcut);
```

Comment: It would be good if you can explain this answer. It has comments, but it just is a code dump. The user who asked the question may want more information

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem. But in my case it worked and failed when I deployed to production. And it failed because production has the latest version of 6to5.
This could be prevented by using `npm shrinkwrap`.
According to the latest ES6 spec you can't use a class like this. https://github.com/babel/babel/issues/700

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same problem. First time I tried to solve problem via ES6 classes but I have problem with $inject my dependencies. After I realized what angular have couple styles of writing code and I tried. At all I used [John Papa](https://github.com/johnpapa/angular-styleguide) styles and I got this works code in my rails app with ES6:

```
((angular) => {
 'use strict';

  var Flash = ($timeout) => {
   return {
     restrict: 'E',
     scope: {
       messages: '=messages'
     },
     template: (() => {
       return "<div class='alert flash-{{ message[0] }}' ng-repeat = 'message in messages'>" +
                "<div class= 'close' ng-click = 'closeMessage($index)' data-dismiss = 'alert' > × </div>" +
                "<span class= 'message' >{{ message[1] }}</ span>" +
              "</ div>";
     }),
     link: (scope) => {
       scope.closeMessage = (index) => {
         scope.messages.splice(index, 1)
       };

      $timeout(() => {
        scope.messages = []
      }, 5000);
    }
  }
};

Flash.$inject = ['$timeout'];

angular.module('Application').directive('ngFlash', Flash);

})(window.angular);
```

I know that I can do little bit improvements with functions and variables in more ES6 style.
I hope it helps.

Comment: Where is a class in this solution ? Question is about Using ES6 Classes in directive, you defined directive as a function just using fat arrow for no reason. Sorry but I don't like this.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this problem just now and I saw this topic. Tried some methods provided in discussion, I finally solved this problem in a very simple way:

```
export default function archiveTreeDirective() {
    'ngInject';

    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        scope: {
            selectedNodes: "="
        },
        templateUrl: 'app/components/directives/archiveTree/archiveTree.html',
        controller: ArchiveTreeController,
        controllerAs: 'vm',
        bindToController: true
    };
}

class ArchiveTreeController {
    constructor() {
        'ngInject';
        ...
    }
    ...
}
```

I directly use function as the .directive('directiveName',factory) argument, and export it, later import it in module declaration. But I missed the "default" statement when exporting, so I got an error. After I add "default" key word, everything works!

I find this method also works in my route configs (also in a function way).

============
Hope you can understand my poor English :)