# Defining and registering Angular directives in a 1.x ES6 project

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, ecmascript-6

I have been working on an Angular project that uses all ES6 syntax with babel-node doing the transpiling. This works nicely for controllers and services, but I'm uncertain how best to write directives for the project. According to posts such as this:

[Using ES6 Classes as Angular 1.x directives](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28620479/using-es6-classes-as-angular-1-x-directives)

writing directives using the ES6 class syntax is hacky, and may not port well to Angular 2.0. What is the recommended approach for reusability and longevity? Should I be using ES5 syntax for directives for the time being, despite the project being all ES6 otherwise? If so, how can I best register the directive if I'm using the import/export syntax for all other modules?

Comment: What would you gain from using the class syntax? It's called directive definition **object** after all and there's only one instance of it. Unlike a controller for instance (no pun intended). If you really want to move forward you might want to take a look at [ng-forward](https://github.com/ngUpgraders/ng-forward) (pun intended).

Comment: use [ngForward](https://github.com/ngUpgraders/ng-forward). That way, you can use NG2 syntax for your ng1 project.