# How to code angular with ES6 properly for this class with webpack?

Tags: angularjs, ecmascript-6, babeljs

I have an index.js file here:

```
const angular = require('angular');
const ngModule = angular.module('app', []);

require('./directives')(ngModule);
```

I am getting this error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: __webpack_require__(...) is not a function
```

How do I correctly change this?

```
require('./directives')(ngModule);
```

I originally had only babel-loader and babel-core installed, but it didnt seem to work. Then I included babel-presets-es2015, but I got that error above. What is the correct way to do this?

My module loaders section of my webpack config has:

```
   loaders: [
      {
        test: /\.js$/,
        loader: 'babel',
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        query: {
          presets: ['es2015']
        }
      }
    ]
```

If I do away with the es2015, I get errors how I may not have the right loader.

The way I have my directives right now is... I have a "directives" directory with:

index.js

```
export default ngModule => {
  require('./testdirect')(ngModule)
};
```

testdirect.js

```
export default ngModule => {
  ngModule.directive('testDirect', () => {
    return {
      restrict: 'E',
      scope: {},
      templateUrl: 'directives/testDirect.html',
      controllerAs: 'vm',
      controller: function() {
        const vm = this;
        vm.greeting = "Hello Webpack";
      }
    }
  });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

With ES6 you need to use **import** instead of **require**

`import angular from 'angular';`

You do need babel-loader, babel-core and babel-presets-es2015

Comment: Assuming that line is changed, what is the proper way to handle: require('./directives')(ngModule);

Comment: how are you exporting your directives?

Comment: Updated original post with details on how my directives are currently being exported.

Comment: might be a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28620479/using-es6-classes-as-angular-1-x-directives/28634429#28634429